# How to use a ternary operator within .buttonStyle() in SwiftUI?

Tags: button, swiftui, struct

I am trying to refactor the logic o a button so I created a buttonStyle with a ternary operator inside of itself, but I am getting two errors:

> Type 'ButtonStyle' has no member 'bordered'
> Type 'ButtonStyle' has no member 'borderedProminent'

this is my code:

```
struct SelectButton: View {
@Binding var isSelecting: Bool
var body: some View{
    if( isSelecting){
        Button(action: {
            self.isSelecting.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text(isSelecting ? "Selecting" : "Select")
        })
        .buttonStyle(isSelecting ? .borderedProminent : .bordered)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
    }
}
```

}

I do not know if a struct or func -> some View is the best way to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't use it's because they have Mismatch types

You can either have one or the other. One is of type `BorderedProminentButtonStyle` while the other is of type `BorderedButtonStyle`

The below code shows how can achieve your result without encapsulating the entire button in a `if` or creating another view.

You create a `View` extension (this way it works for any View) then you can apply properties conditionally.

So here's the `View` extension

```swift
extension View {
    func `if`<Content: View>(_ conditional: Bool, content: (Self) -> Content) -> TupleView<(Self?, Content?)> {
        if conditional {
            return TupleView((nil, content(self)))
        } else {
            return TupleView((self, nil))
        }
    }
}
```

The way to use it would be somewhat simple

```swift
Button(action: {
    self.isSelecting.toggle()
}, label: {
    Text(isSelecting ? "Selecting" : "Select")
})  
    .if(!isSelecting) { $0.buttonStyle(.bordered) }
    .if(isSelecting) { $0.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent) }
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
```

I'm unsure if there's another way to compact this but I tested this on Playground and it works as expected, depending on your view it might or might not introduce bugs

Comment: Using a conditional modifier like the one shown here is generally bad practice in SwiftUI. This causes SwiftUI to lose track of the View due to mismatched identifiers, which can break animations and have other unintended side effects. Proceed with caution.

Read more: https://www.objc.io/blog/2021/08/24/conditional-view-modifiers/